# TagCommander - Fire tag at user's click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I'm using TagCommander and I'm trying to fire a specific tag when a user click or scroll within a certain page.

I can easily detect clicks and scroll and fire an event/set a variable according to that, but I can't find a way to fire a Tag when that happens.

My tag should actually fire according to a specific perimeter (a subset of pages) and when a user does some specific action on the page (i.e. click or scroll).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Could you show us some code

Comment: Javascript code is quite easy and its actually working fine.
My problem is how to then fire a Tag within TagCommander according to the event I'm sending in the code.
Or if it exists any other way to fire a tag at user's click/scroll.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean with tag ? A html tag ?

Comment: TagCommander (http://www.tagcommander.com/en/) tag

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while, maybe you found a solution.
To let a click fire, you should go to:
Triggers > edit > choose "Clicks" from the horizontal menu. Under "selector path" insert the CSS selector path of the Button/Link/Call to Action that you want to track. Click on "done".

If you don't know how to select the CSS selector,
go to your website,
open the chrome console,
activate the tab "Elements",
activate the array,
select with the mouse the Button you want to track
in the Tab "Elements" the Elements will be highlighted in its code
if you go on the line all to the left it will appear 3 points (...), click on them and select "copy selection" > CSS Path
it should be something with #, for example #tab1234